# Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer in iPhone - unable to configure network read stream

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-streaming

I am using the Matt Gallagher's algorithm to perform mp3 streaming in iOS but sometimes when you pause the application and, after some time, resume the song a message pop up: "Unable to configure network stream read". I have analyzed the code, but I do not see how to get around this error. Has anyone managed to cope better with this error?

[Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer code](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)

Comment: Any answers you could share on that?

Comment: I've had this problem when there is no internet connectivity. Could this be a factor? Is it when you are moving from or to wifi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced the same thing with this 3rd party app and could not find a solution for that and then I have tried apple's native avplayer (not avaudioplayer) which gives you the ability to stream with the function `:initWithURL` . here's the class reference, by the way : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

in addition here's my code for playing music :

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:sourceURL];
            theItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
            theItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
            theAudio = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:mainDelegate.theItem];
```

to catch whether the player is readyto play you add the observer above and then you can check it like :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == theItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if(theItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)    
        {
            [theAudio play];
            [theItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        }
        else if(theItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"%@" , mainDelegate.theItem.error.description);
        }
        else if(theItem.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown)
            NSLog(@"unknown");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.